# Validate the receiving email has attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

**Want to validate the receving email has attachment**

```
Set outObj= CreateObject("outlook.Application")
Set outAccount = outObj.Session.Accounts.item(1)
Set nameSpace = outObj.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = outAccount.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set myitem= myFolfer.items.Restrict("[UnRead]=True").GetFirst     
Need Help and my attchment filetype =.rsp
```

Comment: Need help with *what* exactly?  What is it you're having a problem with?  Don't rely on us figuring that out from the title alone.

Comment: I edited the tags because this has nothing to do with UFT, it's pure VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Check `myitem.Attachments.Count > 0`

If you need to check that there is an attachment with a particular extension, loop through the `myitem.Attachments` collection and for each `Attachment` object, check the `Attachment.FileName` property.

Comment: i am new in vbs could you please help me with codes? i want to validate the attachment file type is .rsp